# Connect iMac to Sharp TV, But No Video or Audio

Tags: hdmi, imac

Here’s my setup:

- iMac 21.5” (Late 2009)
- Mac OS X 10.6.7
- Sharp LD-46D85UN
- [Griffin Mini DisplayPort to HDMI](http://store.apple.com/us/product/TY600VC/A)

I've been using my iMac as an HTPC since I purchased it last year, but last week it stopped working. When I connect everything now, the iMac flashes blue as it normally does when connecting an external display but no picture appears on the TV and there's no sound either.

I know the iMac recognizes the TV because it shows up in System Preferences under Displays and under Sound. It has worked perfectly for months and I can't think of a single thing that changed in my setup at all; it worked one day and didn't the next.

Here are the solutions I've found on the net and tried so far:

- Followed different sequences for connecting the pieces of the puzzle, e.g. turn TV on; set to correct input; connect HDMI cable; connect to adapter; connect adapter to iMac
- Restarted all devices
- Applied combo update to Mac OS X
- Repaired permissions on iMac
- Safe booted iMac
- Scrapped all the `com.apple.windowserver.plist` files in /Library/Preferences and in each user's home folder
- Reset PRAM
- Tried different HDMI inputs on my TV, different HDMI cords

I'd really appreciate any help anyone can offer!

Here’s an Apple [support article](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4241) confirming that my model should support video and audio.

Comment: Bought a new adapter and it’s now working.